# Order values in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a bunch of values in column A as shown below and in the current excel sort order

```
A9987
AABASE
AACCT
AACH
AAD
AADJ
AADJ2
```

I need this to be sorted as

```
AABASE
AACCT
AACH
AAD
AADJ
AADJ2
A9987
```

I tried defining a custom list and tried to use that, but that did not work. The custom list had the alphabets first and then the numbers.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322067 - contains lots of advice about sorting.

Comment: tried that but I could not get the desired results, unless I was doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to resort to EBCDIC sorting, but then it worked fine.